# JavaScript Registration Validation Issues

Tags: javascript

everyone! I'm building form validation in HTML/JavaScript. The Problem is that it always behaves like the fields are filled and colors the textboxes in blue.

```
    var fName = document.getElementById('fName').value;
    fName = document.getElementById('fName').focus();
    var lName = document.getElementById('lName').value;

    function validation()
    {



//check empty fields

if (fName == "" || lName == "") 
{
    document.getElementById('fName').style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.getElementById('lName').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}


else(fName != "" || lName != "")
{
    document.getElementById('fName').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.getElementById('lName').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line: `fName = document.getElementById('fName').focus();` `fName` in that line is assigned as `undefined` so you should try something like:

```
var element = document.getElementById('fName'); 
var fName = element.value;
element.focus();
```

When you fire an event or perform some action for example, the returning value is `undefined` so `fName != ""` is true.

E.g.:

```
console.log(element.classList.add("mystyle"));  //return undefined
```

Also check that you should put `else if()` instead of `else ()` full example: https://jsfiddle.net/cmq0x2a6/

Comment: Thank you for the quick respond!  I tried it your way and now absolutely nothing happens. The fields do not color red nor blue.

Comment: @HrNik I've updated the response. Check the example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this:

```
fname
<input type="text" id="fName" onfocus="checkIfEmpty(event)">
lname
<input type="text" id="lName" onfocus="checkIfEmpty(event)">

<script>
    function checkIfEmpty(event) {
        if (event.relatedTarget != null) {
            if (event.relatedTarget.value.length == 0) {
                event.relatedTarget.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            } else event.relatedTarget.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in this typo --

```
else(fName != "" || lName != "")
{
  // set the color to 'blue'
}
```

You miss the `if`, so `(fName != "" || lName != "")` is just an expression that you evaluate and then immediately execute the code inside the curly braces.

It all runs OK because you placed the opening brace on the next line (it would've thrown a `SyntaxError` otherwise).

You need to change your code to

```
else if (fName !== "" || lName !== "") {
  // set the style
}
```